# Host (Ubuntu 18.04) WiFi, Guest Wired recipe with Oracle VirutalBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ethernet

My host machine is running Ubuntu 18.04, and I am connected to a WiFi network A.  I have a ethernet cord plugged in, which is connected to network B, but I can only connect to the internet with a specific MAC address 1234abc (they've got it on a white list).  I would like to connect to network B with my Kali Virtual Machine (Running Oracle VirtualBox) through the ethernet cable and keep my host traffic on network A (via WiFi).  I've made the MAC address of the virtual machine the correct one needed to connect to network B.  Both host and guest connect to the WiFi (Network A) and I'm not sure how to tell the guest to connect via the ethernet card to Network B instead.  What settings do I need to have to connect my virtual machine to Network B via the ethernet?
Thanks!